# Set jQuery flot bar colors based on its score

Tags: jquery, flot

I am new to jQuery flot plugin and I want to set each bar's color based on its score.

For the score of the "Myself" bar:

- 0 - 20: red
- 20 - 70: yellow
- 70 - 100: green

For the score of the "You" bar:

- 0 - 20: blue
- 20 - 70: black
- 70 - 100: orange

**Code Snippet:**

```
$.plot(
  $("#placeholder"),[{
    data: [[1, 81], [3.5, 33]],
    label: 'Myself',
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill: true,
      fillColor: {
        colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}],
        horizontal: true
      },
      align: "center"
    }
  },{
    data: [[2, 18], [4.5, 75]],
    label: 'You',
    color: 'red',
    bars: {
      show: true,
      barWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill: true,
      fillColor: {
        colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}],
        horizontal: true
      },
      align: "center"
    }
  }],{
    xaxis: {
      ticks: [[1.5, '1st half'], [4, '2nd half']],
      min: 0,
      max: 5.5,
      tickLength: 0
    },
    yaxis: {tickLength: 0},
    grid: {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      borderWidth: 0,
      markings: [{xaxis: {from: 0, to: 0}, color: "#909090"}, {yaxis: {from: 0, to: 0}, color: "#909090"}]
  },
  legend: {backgroundOpacity: 0.6, position: 'ne', margin: [-10, 0]},
  valueLabels: {show: true, truncateValue: 2}
});
```

A JSFiddle of the above code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uAGh9/2/). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried to fix the link formatting and it won't let you add a working JSFiddle link without some code, so I've added that. Indented it as best I can...

Answer (score 1):

You *could* implement a custom draw hook like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821786/31967). However when I've needed to do this I've taken a different approach when there are not many ranges.

If you have control over the source data formatting you could create separate series for each of the value ranges and assign the appropriate colours that way. So you'd have the following series: Myself0-20, Myself20-70, Myself70-100, You0-20, You20-70, You70-100.

The only modification from your JSFiddle code is the addition of the new series ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9eCB/)):

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [
  {data: [[1, 0], [3.5, 0]], label: 'Myself0-20', color: 'red', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}},
  {data: [[1, 0], [3.5, 33]], label: 'Myself20-70', color: 'yellow', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}},
  {data: [[1, 81], [3.5, 0]], label: 'Myself70-100', color: 'green', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}},
  {data: [[2, 18], [4.5, 0]], label: 'You0-20', color: 'blue', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}},
  {data: [[2, 0], [4.5, 0]], label: 'You20-70', color: 'black', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}},
  {data: [[2, 0], [4.5, 75]], label: 'You70-100', color: 'orange', bars: {show: true, barWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, fill: true, fillColor: {colors: [{brightness: 1}, {brightness: 0.5}], horizontal: true}, align: "center"}}
],{
  xaxis: {ticks: [[1.5, '1st half'], [4, '2nd half']], min: 0, max: 5.5, tickLength: 0},
  yaxis: {tickLength: 0},
  grid: {backgroundColor: "#ffffff", borderWidth: 0, markings: [{xaxis: {from: 0, to: 0}, color: "#909090"}, {yaxis: {from: 0, to: 0}, color: "#909090"}]},
  legend: {backgroundOpacity: 0.6, position: 'ne', margin: [-10, 0]},
  valueLabels: {show: true, truncateValue: 2}
});
```